# Is there a way to save time by not calculating unnecessary sums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray

### The objective

Given a 2-dimensional array `A`, I have to keep adding +1 to the value of the first row in each column until the sums of the columns equal to the same value, for example 28.

### My solution

It is probably not the best of solutions, but considering the point I'd like to make, it will do. This is meant to be a simplified example. In the original version it is based on a probability distribution whether the first or the second row gets the +1, and it differs among columns. Plus it has to be done one by one, for the probability distribution changes due to whether the first or the second row of a column got the +1 in the previous cycle. So summation of columns and iteration are necessary.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(20).reshape(2, 10)
print(A)

MASK = A.sum(axis=0) < 28
print(A.sum(axis=0) < 28)

while np.any(MASK):
    LUCKYROW = np.repeat(0, np.count_nonzero(MASK))
    A[LUCKYROW, MASK] += 1
    MASK = A.sum(axis=0) < 28
    print(A.sum(axis=0) < 28)
print(A)
```

Let's take a look at the output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True False False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True  True False False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True False False False False False False]
[ True  True  True  True False False False False False False]
[ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
[ True  True  True False False False False False False False]
[ True  True False False False False False False False False]
[ True  True False False False False False False False False]
[ True False False False False False False False False False]
[ True False False False False False False False False False]
[False False False False False False False False False False]
[[18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
```

Alright, it works, but why do I calculate the sum of each column in each cycle? Based on previous cycles I know which column's sum has already reached the target value. If I make use of this information, I can save time maybe.

### My second solution

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(20).reshape(2, 10)
print(A)

MASK = A.sum(axis=0) < 28
print(A.sum(axis=0) < 28)

while np.any(MASK):
    LUCKYROW = np.repeat(0, np.count_nonzero(MASK))
    A[LUCKYROW, MASK] += 1
    MASK[MASK] = A[:, MASK].sum(axis=0) < 28
    print(A[:, MASK].sum(axis=0) < 28)
print(A)
```

And the output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True False]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True  True]
[ True  True  True]
[ True  True  True]
[ True  True]
[ True  True]
[ True]
[ True]
[]
[[18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]]
```

It seems to work. Although one problem emerges. It is **not** faster than the first solution. I have tried with 25000 columns and 74998‬ as target value, but they are roughly equal timewise.

### My request

I think I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of either ndarray operations or ndarray indexing. The second solution should do less and less calculation with each cycle, so I'd expect a significant performance improvement. I am unable to find explanation. Where is my train of thought faulty?

Comment: Applying the mask is as expensive as doing the sum.  We'd have to do more detailed timings but my guess is that the sum is a minor step, and not sensitive to the length summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick demo of how indexing affects sums:

```
In [140]: x = np.arange(10000)                                                       
In [141]: timeit x.sum()                                                             
13.4 µs ± 183 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

summing half the items, even with a fast slice `view` doesn't save that much time:

```
In [142]: timeit x[:5000].sum()                                                      
10.8 µs ± 78.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Advanced indexing or masking is slower:

```
In [143]: %%timeit idx=np.arange(5000) 
     ...: x[idx].sum() 

21.3 µs ± 1.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [144]: %%timeit 
     ...: x[x<=5000].sum() 

34.4 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

On a modern computers basic math like addition isn't that expensive.  Selecting items and iterating through arrays is as expensive, timewise, as the addition itself.

Comment: Ahh, crystal clear! So essentially that is the heart of the matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only changing the first row, you don't need to recalculate the sum of the columns on each iteration.  In fact, since the only change is adding 1 to some elements on the first row you don't need to iterate at all.

```
A = np.arange(20).reshape(2, 10)
s = A.sum(0)
d = max(s) - s
A[0] += d

>>> A
array([[18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

This may not be possible with more complex calculations, but with sums it's an easy shortcut.

There could be a few reasons your "faster" code doesn't actually run faster.
First off, kudos for actually profiling the code.
The first reason is that `A` is very small.
Generally, `numpy` only gives a speed benefit with thousands or tens of thousands of elements in an array.

Second, in the "faster" code the line

```
MASK[MASK] = A[:, MASK].sum(axis=0) < 28
```

creates a copy of all the rows in `A` indexed by `MASK`.
This can be a fairly expensive operation, so summing the extra rows in the original version using `MASK = A.sum(axis=0) < 28` may be quicker simply because it doesn't need that extra copy.

Comment: You are perfectly right about the shortcut considering the code in my question. I sloppily have not made it clear that it is meant to be a simplified example. In the original version it is based on a probability distribution whether the first or the second row gets the +1, and it differs among columns. Plus it has to be done one by one, for the probability distribution changes due to whether the first or the second row of a column got the +1 in the previous cycle.
I am quite ashamed to admit that profiling is a deficiency of mine. I have tried cProfile but I am unsure how to interpret it.